# How do I configure HikariCP with jt400 AS400JDBCDataSource

Tags: hikaricp, jt400

I'm trying to use the HikariCP connection pool (2.4.2) with jt400 AS400JDBCDataSource (8.7).

When I configure the DataSource directly everything works fine and I can use connections.

```
AS400JDBCDataSource ds = new AS400JDBCDataSource();
ds.setUser("user");
ds.setPassword("password");
ds.setServerName("serverName");
ds.setLibraries("libraries");
```

When I configure HikariCP via properties

```
dataSourceClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource
dataSource.user=user
dataSource.password=password
dataSource.libraries=libraries
dataSource.serverName=serverName
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30008ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:196)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:519)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:535)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:137)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
```

Everything is fine when I do the same thing with PostgreSQL:

```
dataSourceClassName=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
dataSource.user=user
dataSource.password=password
dataSource.databaseName=databaseName
dataSource.serverName=serverName
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that I must set connectionTestQuery property with the AS400JDBCDataSource.

```
dataSourceClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource
connectionTestQuery=values 1
dataSource.user=user
dataSource.password=password
dataSource.libraries=libraries
dataSource.serverName=serverName
```

Note that the following also works:

```
driverClassName=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
jdbcUrl=jdbc:as400://serverName;libraries=libraries;naming=system;trace=false;prompt=false;errors=full
connectionTestQuery=values 1
username=username
password=password
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
static DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
    dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:as400://+serverIP+;prompt=false");
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername(username);
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword(password);
    return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
}
```

In main method:

```java
DataSource dataSource =  dataSource();
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Use above or below

```java
AS400JDBCDataSource AS400DataSource = new AS400JDBCDataSource();
AS400DataSource.setUser(userName);
AS400DataSource.setPassword(password);
AS400DataSource.setServerName(host);

DataSource dataSource = AS400DataSource ;
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```